# ¿cómo disponer valores de API con fetch, fuera del bloque de código else?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, variables-globales

hace días estoy con un asunto en querer disponer de un sólo valor, específicamente temp  (la temperatura absoluta ambiente de una API de clima OpenWeatherMap), ya intenté implementar `return` en distintas partes del código por si estaba equivocado, realicé una query duplicada para comprobar si era por el hecho de usar la misma query que se usa para mostrarlo por el browser, implementé variables globales para utilizar la misma variable dentro del bloque y querer disponer por fuera el valor de temp sin éxito, implementé en varios puntos del código `console.log()` de cada variable y función para comprobar la trazabilidad de los datos cuya acción me da claramente a entender que de dentro del bloque de código `else` no sale y no está disponible por fuera y tira un error de  `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: temp is not defined",`.

```js
//se declaran las constantes para desplegar y obtener informacion del DOM
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper"),
infoTxt = document.querySelector(".info-txt"),
CITY = document.querySelector("input"),
LOCATION = document.querySelector("button"),
clima = wrapper.querySelector(".weather-part"),
wIcon = clima.querySelector("img");

// Variable que guradará la url con la key integrada.
let api;

// Función para luego de presionar enter en el input de CITY, procesa dicha CITY y hace el request a la API.
CITY.addEventListener("keyup", e =>{
    //si está sin escritura la CITY el proceso se frena
    if(e.key == "Enter" && CITY.value != ""){
        //funcion para hacer request a la API
        solicitudApi(CITY.value);
    }
});

// Evento que extrae del navegador la ubicación por ip del mismo. 
LOCATION.addEventListener("click", () =>{
        // Obtenidas las coordenadas en el browser, estas se las envian a una función para realizar el request por coordenadas, no por CITY. Si falla se emite alerta.
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(validPosition, errorMessage);
        }else{
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Tu navegador no permite detectar tu LOCATION',
                text: SON.stringify(error),
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Continuar'
            });
        }
    }
);

// Función request a la API por CITY, city como parámetro de la misma. Luego llama a la función fetchData.
function solicitudApi(city){
    api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&lang=es&appid=659448f530b1011e83f181f7e97df12e`;
    fetchData();
};

// Función request a la API por coordenadas, variable position como parámetro de la misma. Position contiene las coordenadas obtenidas por IP del browser. Luego llama a la función fetchData.
function validPosition(position){
    const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
    api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=metric&appid=659448f530b1011e83f181f7e97df12e`;
    fetchData();
};

//mensaje de error en el DOM
function errorMessage(error){
    infoTxt.innerText = error.message;
    infoTxt.classList.add("error");
};

// Extraemos los datos con fetch a la API y lo enviamos a weatherData.
function fetchData(){
    infoTxt.innerText = "Extrayendo datos del clima de la región...";
    infoTxt.classList.add("pending");
    fetch(api).then(res => res.json()).then(result => weatherData(result)).catch(() =>{
        infoTxt.innerText = "UPS! alguna falla surgió";
        infoTxt.classList.replace("Pendiente", "error");
    });
    // Duplicamos el código inecesario para test de variable temp global.
    
    fetch(api).then(res => res.json()).then(result => tempData(result)).catch(() =>{
        infoTxt.innerText = "UPS! alguna falla surgió";
        infoTxt.classList.replace("Pendiente", "error");
    });
    // tempTherm = function tempData(data){let {temp}= data.main;return temp};
    // console.log(temp);
    // return temp;
    
};


// Obtenemos información de API del clima y la almacenamos en las siguientes variables. La fución weatherData despliega en el DOM los datos obtenidos de la API api.openweathermap.org.

// "const {..,..,..}=...;" esta alternativa de asignación crea variables con el mismo nombre de propiedad en el objeto que queremos extraer los valores correspondientes de cada propiedad, como resultado quedan disponibles las variables en forma infigureidual con el mismo nombre de la propiedad que contenía el objeto de origen, así se evita repetir código al tipear la sintaxis "const" el numero de veces por cada valor de las propiedades a extraer en un mismo objeto.

let tempTherm=0;
function weatherData(data){
    if(data.cod == "404"){
        infoTxt.classList.replace("Pendiente", "error");
        infoTxt.innerText = `${inputField.value} CITY INVÁLIDA, ingrese otra ciudad`;
    }else{
        //se seleccionan los datos que nos inmportan del json en forma de objetos y arrays
        console.log(data);
        const city = data.name;
        const country = data.sys.country;
        const {description, id} = data.weather[0];
        const {temp, feels_like, humidity} = data.main;
        // tempTherm = temp;

        clima.querySelector(".temp .numb").innerText = Math.floor(temp);
        clima.querySelector(".desc").innerText = description;//no supe como traducir la descripccion que manda la api de ingles
        clima.querySelector(".lugar span").innerText = `${city}, ${country}`;
        clima.querySelector(".temp .numb-2").innerText = Math.floor(feels_like);
        clima.querySelector(".hum .hum-2").innerText = `${humidity}%`;
        infoTxt.classList.remove("Pendiente", "error");
        infoTxt.innerText = "";
        CITY.value = "";
        wrapper.classList.add("active");
        // ----------------------
        // function thermometer(temp) {
        //     return temp
        // };
        tempTherm = temp;
        console.log(temp);
        console.log(tempTherm);
        return tempTherm ;
    };
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(tempTherm);
    //return tempTherm;
    
};
console.log(tempTherm);
console.log(temp);
// SE ME ESTÁ COMPLICANDO DE CÓMO LOGRAR DISPONIBILIDAD DEL DATO TEPERATURA DE LA CONSTANTE O LA VARIABLE temp y tempTherm RESPECTIVAMENTE


// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Otra prueba mas duplicando código para obtener el mismo valor de temp, aparentemente la falla está en la estructura implicita del fetch, por alguna razón que desconozco en cualquie función vilculada al fetch ni permite disponer de los datos internos en la sentencia de dicha función, en este caso creamos la función tempData() y sigue pasando lo mismo sin disponer de temp por fuera, tal vez será realizar toda la estructura de la aplicación del termómetro gráfico dentro de la fución, y seguimos en el mismo caso, ya que los retornos con return para entregar las etiquetas <figura> tal vez no van a salir del mismo bloque?.
function tempData(data) {
    let {temp} = data.main;
    tempTherm = temp;
    console.log(tempTherm);
    console.log(temp);
    return tempTherm;
};
// Ciclo para crear termómetro gráfico mediante css.
// Convertimos a enteros los °C.

console.log(tempTherm);
console.log(temp);
let tempInt = 28;
//nos está fallando esta conversión de los °C, no reconoce la constante temp.

// generamos una variable para alternar incremento o decremento en el ciclo for y decidimos insertar el condicional ternario ya dentro del ciclo for.
// tempDownUp = (tempInt >= 0) ? (+1) : (-1) ;

// Función para adicionar elemento en el html[FALTA TEST OK].
function addElemento(texto){
    var capa = document.getElementById("capa");
    var figure = document.createElement("figure");
    h1.innerHTML = texto;
    capa.appendChild(figure);
};

// Iteración por cada °C para generar columna en colores mediante css [FALTA TEST OK].
for (let temp = 0; temp <= tempInt; temp = (tempInt >= 0) ? (+1) : (-1)) {
    if( temp <(-20)) {
        '<figure class="dangFreezz"></figure>'
    } else if ( temp >=(-20)&&temp<(-10)) {        
        '<figure class="freezz"></figure>'
    } else if ( temp >=(-10)&&temp<(0)) {        
        '<figure class="cool"></figure>'
    } else if ( temp >=(0)&&temp<(15)) {        
        '<figure class="fresh"></figure>'
    } else if ( temp >=(15)&&temp<(30)) {        
        '<figure class="templ"></figure>'
    } else if ( temp >=(30)&&temp<(45)) {        
        '<figure class="heat"></figure>'
    } else {        
        '<figure class="dangHeat"></figure>'
    };
} ;
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
};
/* 45°C */
div .dangHeat {
    background: 5px 2px red;
}
/* 30°C */
div .heat {
    background: 5px 2px rgb(255, 179, 0);
};
/* 25°C */
div .templ {
    background: 5px 2px rgb(255, 179, 0);
};
/* 15°C */
div .fresh {
    background: 5px 2px blue;
};
/* 0°C */
div .cool {
    background: 5px 2px lightblue
};
/* -10°C */
div .freezz {
    background: 5px 2px silver;
};
/* -20°C */
div .dangFreezz {
    background: 5px 2px violet;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta keywords="clima, tiempo, lluvia, temperatura, humedad">
    <meta description="Sencilla aplicación para consultar el estado del clima por ubicación">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://img.icons8.com/officel/80/000000/afternoon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sencilla aplicación del clima</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="inputCity">
        <input type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="   Escribe tu ciudad de consulta" required>
        <button class="geoFind">Obtener datos del clima según tu geoubicación</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper" id="contenedor">
        <p class="info-txt"></p>
        <div>
            <section class="weather-part mt-4">
                <div class="temp">
                <span>Temperatura&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="numb"></span>
                <span class="deg">°</span>C
                </div>
                
                <div class="temp">
                <span>Sensación térmica&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="numb-2">_</span>
                <span class="deg">°</span>C
                </div>
                
                <div class="hum">
                <span>Humedad &nbsp;</span>
                <span class="hum-2"></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="desc "></div>
                
                <div class="lugar">
                <span></span>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <figure class="dangHeat"></figure>
    <figure class="templ"></figure>
    <figure class="heat"></figure>
    <figure class="fresh"></figure>
    <figure class="cool"></figure>
    <figure class="freezz"></figure>
    <figure class="dangFreezz"></figure>
    <figure class=""></figure>
    <figure class=""></figure>
    <figure class=""></figure>
    <figure class=""></figure>
    <figure class=""></figure>
    <figure class=""></figure>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://github.com/MYGUDEV/WEATHER-APP.git

Comparto el código de modo resumido de como está en el repositorio:

```
//se declaran las constantes para desplegar y obtener informacion del DOM
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper"),
infoTxt = document.querySelector(".info-txt"),
CITY = document.querySelector("input"),
LOCATION = document.querySelector("button"),
clima = wrapper.querySelector(".weather-part"),
wIcon = clima.querySelector("img");

// Variable que guradará la url con la key integrada.
let api;

// Función para luego de presionar enter en el input de CITY, procesa dicha CITY y hace el request a la API.
CITY.addEventListener("keyup", e =>{
    //si está sin escritura la CITY el proceso se frena
    if(e.key == "Enter" && CITY.value != ""){
        //funcion para hacer request a la API
        solicitudApi(CITY.value);
    }
});
```

Pasamos el parámetro CITY por un input de la ciudad escrita:

```
// Función request a la API por CITY, city como parámetro de la misma. Luego llama a la función fetchData.
function solicitudApi(city){
    api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&lang=es&appid=659448f530b1011e83f181f7e97df12e`;
    fetchData();
};

//mensaje de error en el DOM
function errorMessage(error){
    infoTxt.innerText = error.message;
    infoTxt.classList.add("error");
};

// Extraemos los datos con fetch a la API y lo enviamos a weatherData.
function fetchData(){
    infoTxt.innerText = "Extrayendo datos del clima de la región...";
    infoTxt.classList.add("pending");
    fetch(api).then(res => res.json()).then(result => weatherData(result)).catch(() =>{
        infoTxt.innerText = "UPS! alguna falla surgió";
        infoTxt.classList.replace("Pendiente", "error");
    });
    // Duplicamos el código inecesario para test de variable temp global.
    
    fetch(api).then(res => res.json()).then(result => tempData(result)).catch(() =>{
        infoTxt.innerText = "UPS! alguna falla surgió";
        infoTxt.classList.replace("Pendiente", "error");
    });
    // tempTherm = function tempData(data){let {temp}= data.main;return temp};
    // console.log(temp);
    // return temp;
    
};
```

El inconveniente se puede registrar en esta función en el bloque `else`ya que en terminal las variables `temp` `tempTherm` están sin disponibilidad por fuera del bloque.

```
let tempTherm=0;
function weatherData(data){
    if(data.cod == "404"){
        infoTxt.classList.replace("Pendiente", "error");
        infoTxt.innerText = `${inputField.value} CITY INVÁLIDA, ingrese otra ciudad`;
    }else{
        //se seleccionan los datos que nos inmportan del json en forma de objetos y arrays
        console.log(data);
        const city = data.name;
        const country = data.sys.country;
        const {description, id} = data.weather[0];
        const {temp, feels_like, humidity} = data.main;
        // tempTherm = temp;

        clima.querySelector(".temp .numb").innerText = Math.floor(temp);
        clima.querySelector(".desc").innerText = description;//no supe como traducir la descripccion que manda la api de ingles
        clima.querySelector(".lugar span").innerText = `${city}, ${country}`;
        clima.querySelector(".temp .numb-2").innerText = Math.floor(feels_like);
        clima.querySelector(".hum .hum-2").innerText = `${humidity}%`;
        infoTxt.classList.remove("Pendiente", "error");
        infoTxt.innerText = "";
        CITY.value = "";
        wrapper.classList.add("active");
        // ----------------------
        // function thermometer(temp) {
        //     return temp
        // };
        tempTherm = temp;
        console.log(temp);
        console.log(tempTherm);
        return tempTherm ;
    };
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(tempTherm);
    //return tempTherm;
    
};
console.log(tempTherm);
console.log(temp);
// SE ME ESTÁ COMPLICANDO DE CÓMO LOGRAR DISPONIBILIDAD DEL DATO TEPERATURA DE LA CONSTANTE O LA VARIABLE temp y tempTherm RESPECTIVAMENTE
```

Tengan paciencia al que lea este post ya que como todos los juniors recién empiezo y estoy con sed de aprender lo que me falta conocer y practicar. Seguramente tendré errores, que son bienvenidos mencionarlos.

Saludos! y gracias.

Por lo pronto que me respondieron A.Cedano y Yussef, entiendo que es un tema largo de resolver, ya que está implicado el funcionamiento de fetch, por lo pronto tenía entendido que se consultaba un dato y ese dato se disponía libremente, ahora hay instancias tácitas que necesito estudiar mas como la cuestión de multihilos y utilizar de algún modo callbacks, tal vez.
El año pasado vi otra forma de consumir API con next.js, y lo que recuerdo que era un poco más sencillo de entenderlo, y alguna ventaja creo que también tenía, tal vez necesite volver a releer todo lo del año pasado y ver si aplico next, aunque fetch necesito conocerlo y usarlo al menos como una herramienta mas. gracias colegas.

Comment: Las llamadas a `fetch` son asíncronas, significa que podría haber un tiempo de espera mientras la petición se procesa (aquí debes olvidarte de la programación habitual, línea por línea), JS es multihilo, está escrito de modo que puedan seguir ocurriendo otras cosas en el hilo principal mientras llamadas como `fetch` terminan. Entonces te quedan dos caminos: 1. Invocar el siguiente paso desde dentro de `fetch`, o 2. Implementar un *callback*.

Comment: @A.Cedano La única forma de ocupar otro hilo en JS es usando workers. Las funciones asíncronas se ejecutan en el mismo hilo de la aplicación

Comment: @Yussef lo que quise decir es que mientras se procesan las llamadas asíncronas otras cosas pueden seguir ocurriendo en el mismo hilo principal, por tanto, en peticiones como fetch o Ajax no podemos pensar en la típica programación funcional, línea por línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando acceder de forma síncrona a un dato que se obtiene de forma asíncrona (te recomendaría mirar [Asincronía en Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)).

En resumen, debes esperar a que la operación asíncrona se resuelva antes de proceder a usar cualquier valor que dependa de esta. El siguiente ejemplo ilustra el problema:

```js
var global = null;

// esta función asigna un valor a la variable global de manera síncrona
function _sync(val) {
  global = val;
}

// esta función asigna un valor a la variable global de manera asíncrona
function _async(val) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    global = val;
  }, 0);
}

_async(1); // demora un poco en procesarse
_sync(2); // se procesa inmediatamente

console.log(global); // 2

// despues de un tiempo:
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(global); // 1
}, 0);
```

En tu caso particular estás usando `Promises` (Promesas, con la api `fetch`), que básicamente son un mecanismo que te permite manejar este tipo de situaciones, habilitando una forma de acceder al resultado de la operación asíncrona después de que esta termina:

```js
var global = null;

// esta función asigna un valor a la variable global de manera asíncrona
function _async(val) {
  // se retorna una Promesa:
  return new Promise(function (done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      global = val;
      // "done" se llama obligatoriamente aquí para indicar que la operación terminó
      // le puedes pasar argumentos a esta función (data):
      done(val);
    }, 1000); // esta operación toma 1 segundo en completarse
  });
}

// esta función retorna una promesa por lo tanto puedes usar el método "then":
_async(1).then(function(val) {
  // "then" garantiza que la operación asíncrona terminó y ya puedes acceder a la info
  // "val" es el mismo argumento que se pasó a la función "done"
  console.log('val: ' + val); // 1
  console.log('global: ' + global); // 1
  
  // de aquí en adelante puedes seguir encadenando llamados "then"
  // los argumentos del siguiente "then" será lo que retornes en el anterior.
  // por ejemplo, si aqui multiplico (val * 10) y lo retorno:
  return val * 10; // 1 * 10 = 10;
}).then(function(result) {
  // result = 10
  console.log(result);
  // y así sucesivamente...
});

// aquí no estamos en el contexto del "then", por eso este código
// se ejecuta inmediatamente (sin esperar) y no tenemos el valor actualizado:
console.log('global: ' + global); // null
```

Ahora, analiza bien tu código y te darás cuenta que sucede exactamente lo mismo:

```
fetch(api)
  .then((res) => res.json()) // esta linea convierte la respuesta en formato json
  .then((result) => weatherData(result)) // esta es tu función
  .then((data) => weatherData2(data)) // <-- encadena otro "then"
  ...

function weatherData(data) {
  ...
  // si retornas data aquí, la siguiente función "then" 
  // podrá seguir usando la misma información:
  return data;
}

function weatherData2(data) {
  // sigues teniendo acceso a data
}
```

**PD:** Existen casos en los que quieres disponer de esta data de manera "global" en tu aplicación, es decir, no solamente ejecutar código inmediatamente después de que la información carga sino eventualmente cuando el usuario realiza alguna acción pasado un tiempo. Estos casos son muy comunes y se denominan "estrategias de manejo de estado de aplicación", un concepto más avanzado en el mundo del frontend y patrones de diseño (por si quieres investigar al respecto). Antes de eso te recomiendo dominar todos estos conceptos de asincronía (callbacks, promesas, async/await, etc), modularidad y muy importante el tema de **closure** ya que las variables "globales" no son una buena práctica.